# options in jaas authorisation policy file

Tags: java, authentication, authorization, jaas

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Configuration Error:
Line 1: expected [option key], found [null]

This the error which I am facing now in my java policy file:
the policy file contains the following code

grant {"file:C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 9.0/webapps/doctor/admin.html" "required",Principal "C/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 9.0/webapps.doctor/WEB-INF/classes/java-files/DaPrincipal.java" } "Admin" {
permission java.io.FilePermission "admin.html", "read","write"
};

Comment: Before the first close curly bracket there is a comma. Before the second, a semicolon. Should it be the problem?

Comment: I tried your way but I am getting the same error